# MySql Stored Procedure Select Table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Where I have more than one table in my database for use with (similar, but) different products.

Is it possible to select a table to work with based on a parameter (example below)? 
(This would save me having multiple similar copies of the same procedure).

---

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dostuff` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `dostuff`(IN prod_code VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN

IF INSTR(prod_code, 'product_a') THEN
    myTable = product_a_table
ELSE IF INSTR(prod_code, 'product_b') THEN
    myTable = product_b_table
END IF

-- do stuff on myTable such as SELECT and UPDATE

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create a command like this:

```
SET @query := CONCAT("REPAIR TABLE ", @tableName);             
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;             
EXECUTE stmt;             
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

As you can see, you can push any string/variable you want into that command (using variables wherever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible to have variable table names in a query.

Our very own [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) explains [here](http://www.1-script.com/forums/MySQL-dynamic-table-name-within-query-article3168--22.htm)

> Table names, column names, etc. cannot be dynamic in the way you
>   describe. This is not permitted by the SQL language, for many reasons.
>
> For instance, there would be no way for the query optimizer to decide
>   which index(es) to use, if it doesn't know at parse time which tables
>   and columns are being queried.

Answer (score 0):

I think really the issue is whether your database has the required level of normalisation. Why is "ProductGroup" not a field on a sinlge product table, thus allowing you to select rows where the ProductGroup has a certain value?

Comment: Because each product has different parameter sets, and so require unique tables.

Comment: And to add further complications, the parameter sets may increase in the future, and I would require to work with differing versions also.